# Multiple Checkbox with Model returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

after I read data from my database, I try to show those datas in Html.Helper checkbox and I do that. But later when I try to get checked values back to the controller, model always returns null. Here's my controller part:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult NewClient()
    {
        HizmetModel hizmetModel = new HizmetModel();

        hizmetModel.hizmet = db.Hizmet.ToList<Hizmet>();

        return View(hizmetModel);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewClientPost(string name, string lastname, string telephone, string plate, HizmetModel hizmet)
    {
        Musteri musteri = new Musteri();
        if (!db.Musteri.Where(x => x.plaka == plate).Any())
        {
            musteri.isim = name;
            musteri.soyisim = lastname;
            musteri.telefon = telephone;
            musteri.plaka = plate;
            db.Musteri.Add(musteri);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        Islem islem = new Islem();
        IslemHizmet islemhizmet = new IslemHizmet();
        islem.giristarihi = DateTime.Now;
        islem.plaka = plate;
        var selectedHizmet = hizmet.hizmet.Where(x => x.isChecked == true).ToList<Hizmet>();
        db.Islem.Add(islem);
        db.SaveChanges();
        var onprocessplate = db.Islem.Where(x => x.plaka == plate).FirstOrDefault();
        foreach (var item in selectedHizmet)
        {
            islemhizmet.islem_id = onprocessplate.islem_id;
            islemhizmet.hizmet_id = item.hizmet_id;
            db.IslemHizmet.Add(islemhizmet);
            db.SaveChanges();
            islemhizmet = new IslemHizmet();
        }

        TempData["Success"] = "Müşteri başarıyla eklendi...";
        return RedirectToAction("CurrentClients", "Admin");
    }
```

This is my model for the list:

```
public class HizmetModel
{
    public List<Hizmet> hizmet { get; set; }
}
```

I use this model in the cshtml file:

```
@model otoyikama.Models.Model.HizmetModel
```

And this is the loop for displaying checkboxes

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.hizmet.Count; i++)
            {
                <li>
                    <label>@Model.hizmet[i].hizmetisim</label>

                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.hizmet[i].isChecked)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.hizmet[i].hizmet_id)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.hizmet[i].hizmetisim)
                </li>
            }
```

I couldn't figure what's the problem here, my get action works fine, I can see all the data from database but I can't pass them back to controller.

Comment: that customer, how much he/she able to choose those services *? just one or more ?

Comment: @BerkGarip more than one

Answer (score 0):

As a first think , u need to create a object in your controller parameters such as like `List<int> serviceIDs` or `List<Service> services` so you can keep more data than one.

The html part:

```
@foreach(item in Model.Service)
{
  <label>@item.ServiceName</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="services" value="@item.ServiceID">
 <input type="hidden" name="services" value="@item.ServiceName">
}
```

The backend part:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewClientPost(string name, string lastname, string telephone, string plate, List<Service> services)
    {
     
    }
```

when u do in that way, u will able to hold more services than to one and i think u can pass them the controller more easly.

when i face with that stuation, im taking those services ID's and calling them on the controller side like bellow;

The html part:

```
@foreach(item in Model.Service)
{
  <label>@item.ServiceName</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="serviceIDs" value="@item.ServiceID">
}
```

The backend part:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewClientPost(string name, string lastname, string telephone, string plate, List<int> serviceIDs)
    { 
      List<Service> services= new List<Service>();
      foreach(var item in serviceIDs)
      {
       var service=db.Service.Where(x => x.ServiceID == item).Any()
         if(service.Count!=0)
            {
              services.Add(service);
            }
      }
    }
```

Comment: they are between in a ```<form> </form>``` form tag right ?

Comment: maybe u should edit your answer and show us to whole html